# How to show Matplotlib Graph/chart in guizero?

Tags: gui, matplotlib

I was working with this piece of code and it is not working . Or maybe I don't know how to do it. What I am trying to do is putting a matplotlib plot in guizero. Is there a way to do it?

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from guizero import App, Text,TextBox,PushButton

fig, ax = plt.subplots()  # Create a figure containing a single axes.
ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 2, 3]);  # Plot some data on the axes.
fig = plt.figure()  # an empty figure with no Axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()  # a figure with a single Axes
#fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)  # a figure with a 2x2 grid of Axes
plt.show()

input_text=''
def do_nothing():
    input_text=input_box.value
    text.value=input_box.value


app = App()
input_box = TextBox(app)
text = Text(app, text="The value")
button = PushButton(app, command=do_nothing)
app.display()
```

Comment: Looks like off-topic to me. What is Pi specific in this question?

Comment: @Vadim but I am doing it on py. Could be another issue. Can't say anything.

Comment: Are you sure it is at all possible to plot MPL figures inside guizero UI? Quick search didn't give any meaningful results...